# Azure Web App (Linux): “Error: Container didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080” - when using: “start”: “pm2 start server.js”

Tags: azure, docker, node.js, azure-app-services, azure-devops

My App Service Linux instance crashes if my node app is using the start script: `"start": "pm2 start server.js"`:

```
2019-04-15 11:36:34.432 ERROR - Container crime-digest__6ea5_0 for site crime-digest__6ea5 has exited, failing site start
2019-04-15 11:36:34.489 ERROR - Container crime-digest__6ea5_0 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 8080, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Container logs have nothing but the above error. If I use just: `"start": "node server.js",` the app starts just fine.

I understand that if the container doesn't respond via 8080 the container gets stopped, but I'm having `process.env.PORT` set as the port of my server so I can't figure out why the pm2 start script crashes the container.

I have a feeling that `process.env.PORT` is undefined if using the above start script because of some mixup in the process but can't find any way to debug it because **after the container crashes I'm unable to ssh into it any more** to inspect it.

I would really appreciate any suggestion,
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the application setting PORT with the value of whatever port your app is listening on.

Ref: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34451